# Windows command line tool like PUSHD (cycle round a list of directories)

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a Windows command line tool that behaves like the linux version - if you have anumber of directories on the stack then `pushd` with no arguments cycles round that list of directories.

**Edit** I am interested in XP and Vista.   I appreciate the OS have a `pushd` and  `popd` command but they don't behave in the same way as the linux bash version

Comment: What exactly is the cycling behavior? Googling for `pushd cycle` just returns references to this page.

Comment: On many *nix shells, including `bash`, the `pushd` command with no arguments rearranges the stack of remembered locations, making one of the others current. Used multiple times, this can cycle you through several remembered places. It is quite handy once you get used to it. The Windows version does not do this trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at "Cd Deluxe" for a greatly improved "change directory" command: http://www.plan10.com/cdd/.

Answer (score 0):

[pushd & popd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushd_and_popd) are available in the windows [powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx).  Now installed by default in Windows 7,

Comment: They're even available in `cmd`, at least on Windows XP, but not with the cycling behavior AFAIR.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect solution, but maybe you could look at [Take Command](http://jpsoft.com/help/index.htm?navigation.htm).  Alternatively, it's almost certainly possible to modify the pushd & popd commands in PowerShell to do what you want.

Comment: Looks like it does roughly what I want.  Will have a look.